# Microsoft BCP Username and Password Encrypt On the Wire?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bcp

I want to use Microsoft BCP to access Azure SQL using SQL Authentication. When I do so, will the username and password passed on the command line be encrypted over the wire? Because access to Azure SQL necessarily goes over the internet, BCP with SQL Authentication can't be used securely if the password goes across in clear text. 
I see from a previous post that the "-X" flag forces this for Sybase BCP, but this option is not listed for SQL Server BCP. Does Microsoft BCP do this by default?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the password will be encrypted over the wire. Login TDS packets from BCP are encrypted like all Microsoft SQL Server client applications. Additionally, Azure SQL Database requires TLS encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan Gao (MSFT) wrote [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2763.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-encryption.aspx) the following: "Regardless of the client library chosen, data is transferred using tabular data stream (TDS) over a secure sockets layer (SSL). Windows Azure SQL Database doesn’t support unencrypted connections. This will ensure data transmission is secure and can help prevent  man-in-the-middle Jump  attacks.

**The handshake for encryption is done in the  PRELOGIN Jump  stream** of the TDS protocol which is required by any client communicating with SQL Server and SQL Database.